# How to reparent a fragment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a framelayout (A) as a base view in my baseActivity, I then add an additional view (B), which may include a SearchFragment.  I want to remove the SearchFragment from this layout B and add it to the outer layout A.

```
 private void reparentSearchFragment(ViewGroup view, FrameLayout container){
    View search = view.findViewById(R.id.search_fragment);
        if(search != null && view instanceof ViewGroup){
            view.removeView(search);
            container.addView(search);
    } 
}
```

This seems to be failing, logs are `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

I find this odd, as I am removing the view, as you can see in the code snippet.  Any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: how do you add the fragment to the B-layout? from java or xml?

Comment: The fragment is listed in the B-layout in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add fragment to B layout dinamically from code.

And when you need to put it in A, you will have to remove fragment and add it again like this:

```
SearchFragment s = ...;
FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
t.remove(s);
t.add(R.layout.A_ID, s);
t.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using dynamic fragments (not added from xml layout files), then use the FragmentTransaction apis.